# Vector3.Lerp inside a Coroutine is not working as it should on Unity3D

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

I am having a strange issue when using a `Vector3.Lerp` inside a coroutine and it makes no sense because I have many Coroutines in my game and they are all working fine.

### **WHAT I AM TRYING TO ACHIEVE**

I am simply trying to move an object from a **starting** height to a **final** height with a  coroutine called `InVolo()` and a simple `Vector3.Lerp` to change the position of the object.

### **MY CODE**

```
float elapsedTime = 0f;

    while (elapsedTime < TempoSalita)
    {


        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, 
            new Vector3(transform.position.x, maxHight, transform.position.z), (elapsedTime / TempoSalita));


        elapsedTime += Time.deltaTime;

        yield return null;
    }

    transform.position = new Vector3(transform.position.x, maxHight, transform.position.z);
    yield return null;
```

The `maxHight` is simply 4f and `TempoSalita` is 2f. The coroutine is started in an **OnTriggerEnter** and it is working fine, the object is reaching the y of 4f and it exits the while in 2 seconds.

### **THE PROBLEM**

Basically, `elapsedTime / TempoSalita` is becoming **1** after 2 seconds, as it should be, but the object reaches the ending position after like 0.3 seconds, when `elapsed/TempoSalita` is 0.2 and it makes no sense to me. Vector3.Lerp should go from **startpos** to **endpos** in the time of the **t** value to go from 0 to 1. But it goes to the final position in 0.2 seconds and I don't have a clue why.

### **WHAT I TRIED**

I have tried to `Debug.Log` the elapsedTime and it is changing fine, tried to use only `Mathf.Lerp` between the y values and it does the same thing. There is nothing else in that script that can affect it, this is how the Coroutine starts:

```
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if(other.CompareTag("Saltino"))
    {
        StartCoroutine(InVolo());
        
    }
}
```

It starts only one time. Do you know what can cause this strange problem?

Comment: `Vector3.Lerp should go from startpos to endpos` yes but you always use the current position as startpos => you interpolate from an already advanced position and the rest of "animation" just moves very very slow since start and end position are getting closer together

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It could be the condition you are using which seems a bit suspect to me.

Generally I would write this a bit differently, something like..

```
var t = 0f;
var start = transform.position;
var target = new Vector3(transform.position.x, maxHight, transform.position.z);

while (t < 1)
{
    t += Time.deltaTime / TempoSalita;

    if (t > 1) t = 1;

    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(start, target, t);

    yield return null;
}
```

First you have your start and target values created before altering the position.  The t value will increase until it reaches (or passes) 1.  Since we do not want t to go beyond 1 we do a check before applying the lerp.  Our t value is calculated outside of the lerp to make it clear and easy to read/modify.

The above will run for time specified and does not require the extra lines at the end since t will eventually be exactly 1.

Comment: I am not sure why this is working, but GOD it is working, thanks!

Comment: @Leoverload to study more about lerp and this code works, you can refer to this awesome article: https://chicounity3d.wordpress.com/2014/05/23/how-to-lerp-like-a-pro/

Comment: @Leoverload I'm sorry; I genuinely do not know.

Comment: The issue is not the condition at all but that OP always uses the current position as start value for the `Lerp` => The start and end position are getting closer together each time => the rest of the loop the object just moves in extremely small steps

Comment: Got it, thanks Darth @derHugo the wise :D